# Probabilty of four events with union and intersection

Tags: probability

I know the union and intersection of three events is given by :
$P(A\cap (B \cup C)) = P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap C))$
$=P(A\cap B)+P(B \cap C)-P(A\cap B \cap C)$
But how to get $P(A\cap (B \cup C) \cap D)$ ?

Comment: Write $X = A \cap D,$ then you have $X \cap (B \cup C).$

Comment: As a minor constructive criticism, you are better off analyzing equivalent events, rather than equivalent probabilities of events.  For example, I would have posted the question as asserting that $$A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C).$$  Then, I would reason that since the LHS and RHS events represent the same event, they must have the same probability of occurrence.